# How to Count Unique Users Logged in?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can someone help me with a SQL Server query to calculate the following metrics:

- Total number of registered users.(If a User has logged in, then it is considered as registered)
- Active users (Active user" is defined as 1+ login during the last 30 days)
- Active users by Device Type
- iPhone App = ??
- Android App = ??

My table looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYOMT.jpg)

Thank you so much, I used the following SQL to generate the data set I put in my example.

```
  SELECT  
SUB1.First_NM,  
SUB1.Last_NM,  
SUB1.Customer_ID,  
SUB1.Conversion_date,  
SUB1.APP_TYPE,  
SUB1.Device_Typ,  
CONVERT (VARCHAR (7),MAX(SUB1.Most_Recent_App_Login),120) as LATEST_App_Login  
FROM  
(  
SELECT   
CASE   
WHEN A.USER_AGNT_STR LIKE '%ANDROID%'   
then 'Android'  
WHEN A.USER_AGNT_STR LIKE '%iPad%'   
then 'iPad'   
WHEN A.USER_AGNT_STR LIKE '%iPhone%'     
THEN 'iPhone' ELSE NULL END AS APP_TYPE,  
B.Customer_ID,  
A.DEVICE_TYP,  
B.First_nm,  
B.Last_NM,  
CONVERT(VARCHAR (7),MAX(B.File_CREATE_DT),120) as Conversion_Date,  
CONVERT (VARCHAR (7),MAX(A.LOGIN_DTTM),120) as Most_Recent_App_Login  
FROM [Tabl1]] A  
JOIN [Tabl2] B  
on A.USER_ID = B.FILE_USER_ID  
AND A.PROD_DT = B.PROD_DT  
WHERE A.USER_AGNT_STR like '%FRB Banking/%'  
AND B.PROD_DT >= dateadd(day, -360, getdate())  
GROUP BY A.USER_AGNT_STR,A.DEVICE_TYP,B.Customer_ID, B.FIRST_NM, B.Last_NM  
HAVING   
A.USER_AGNT_STR like '%iPhone%'  
or A.USER_AGNT_STR like '%iPad%'    
or A.USER_AGNT_STR like '%Android%'  
OR A.DEVICE_TYP like '%Phone%'  
OR A.DEVICE_TYP LIKE '%Tablet%'  
OR A.DEVICE_TYP LIKE '%Android%'  
AND B.Customer_ID <> ' '  
AND B.FIRST_NM != 'Placeholder'  
) SUB1  
GROUP BY Customer_ID, APP_TYPE, First_NM, Last_NM, Conversion_Date, Device_Typ  
order by Customer_ID
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You're expected to put forth some amount of effort, in the form of code or queries you've tried, errors you've encountered, sample data, and expected results.

Comment: Hi, thanks I know this not a free code writing service. This is my first time in asking a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Take a look at the Help section. It has a lot of information on how to get the most out of the site. :)
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This would be a start.  You could use UNION if you want one record set (e.g., change "RegisteredUsers" to a column [PropertyName]) with the value in a [PropertValue] column.

```
select Count(distinct UserId) as [RegisteredUsers]
from TABLE

select Count(distinct UserId) as [ActiveUsers]
from TABLE
where LastLogin >= DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
group by DeviceType

select DeviceType, Count(distinct UserId)
from TABLE 
where LastLogin >= DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
group by DeviceType

select ApplType, Count(distinct UserId)
from TABLE 
where LastLogin >= DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
group by ApplType
```

Comment: Thank you so much Randy, I have added the SQL I created to get the data set from my example